# Start an Auto Swap in azure using TFS

Tags: azure, tfs, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

I'm using VSO to continuously deploy to azure.

I have three slots :

- Staging ( for automated tests )
- AutoSwap ( if the version passes the automated tests in staging, it's deployed to AutoSwap )
- Production ( When AutoSwap is deployed, it will auto swaps with Production ).

The problem is that my deployments are done using FTP ( I can't do it otherwise because it's an Asp.net Core 1.0 app ), so when I deploy to AutoSwap, it's not detected as an actual deployment so no auto swap is done with production.

My question : Is there any powershell command that I can call from the TFS task to start that auto swapping ? ( A command to tell for example that a deployment has been done which I can call when the FTP uploading ends ) ?

**EDIT**
I have found and tried this but it does simply nothing ( it doesn't fail ) :

Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name "MyApp" -Slot1 "production" -Slot2 "AutoSwap" -Force

Comment: MS provides a way to deploy Asp.net Core App with web deploy from VSTS you may want to try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/deploy-aspnet5

Comment: I used to deploy with this but it doesn't work yet for RC2, and with FTP and powershell I have the this feeling of freedom and knowing exactly what happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using this utility to upload the files via FTP :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task

In its code there is this line which should be commented to not to block azure commands in the tasks following it :

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$CurrentSession.ignoreCert}

Now everything works great, It took me one week to find it, I hope that this answer will save time to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Move-AzureDeployment, which swaps the deployments in production and staging.

```
Parameter Set: Default
Move-AzureDeployment [-ServiceName] <String> [ <CommonParameters>]
```

More details you can refer the link from MSDN: [Move-AzureDeployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152834.aspx)

Note: This applies only to cloud services, not web apps. The difference between Web APP and cloud service:  [Web App vs Cloud Service](http://scottge.net/2015/10/07/azure101-web-app-vs-cloud-service/)

**Update**

This may caused by the azure powershell script loads from VSO online does not support swap-slot. Try to remove the Azure powershell module, and import a different one.

See the answer from *Ryan P* in this MSDN link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0f30b76b-7954-4558-a10d-6a2b6635765a/switchazurewebsiteslot-does-not-work-in-vso-online

Comment: This may caused by the azure powershell script loads from VSO online does not support swap-slot. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to put this before the Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot but it didn't help :

Remove-Module Azure
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1"